# Sum with binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics

How to find the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{m} k\binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{m-k}$?

I also would be glad to know the generating function $\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{m-k}x^k$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: To find the sum, use the identity $k\binom{n}k=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$, and then apply [Vandermonde’s identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity).

Comment: Oh, yes. Thank you!

Comment: @Hypsoline: You’re welcome!